# JCheckBoxes not being disabled after I setEnable(false) them

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jframe, enable-if

If have 30 checkboxes and I don't want more than 6 of them to be checked. I have an int keeping track of how many are checked. Each box has an item listener which calls a method to see what that int is at, and if it reaches 6, the method calls the setEnabled(false) on each box. 
However, even after the int number_of_boxes_checked reaches 6 the boxes don't get disabled.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class JLottery2 extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
int number_of_boxes_checked = 1;
JCheckBox[] checkBox = new JCheckBox[30];
JLabel label = new JLabel("0");

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                JLottery2 frame = new JLottery2();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public JLottery2() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 586, 360);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(10, 11, 321, 299);
    contentPane.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 6, 0, 0));

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBounds(330, 11, 230, 299);
    contentPane.add(panel_1);

    panel_1.add(label);

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
        checkBox[i] = new JCheckBox(Integer.toString(i + 1));
        panel.add(checkBox[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
        checkBox[i].addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                limit_checkBoxes();
            }
        });
    }
}

public void limit_checkBoxes() {
    label.setText(Integer.toString(number_of_boxes_checked));
    if (number_of_boxes_checked > 6) {
        for (int i = 0; i > 30; ++i) {
            checkBox[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
        ++number_of_boxes_checked;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Comment: As a side note to the OP, the line `checkBox[i].setEnabled(false);` isn't very user-friendly. How does the user change their mind once they check the 6th box?  They'll all be disabled.  Perhaps only disabling the remaining unchecked boxes with `checkBox[i].setEnabled(checkbox[i].isSelected())`.  You would then have to add code in the `else` block to ensure that all are enabled if the count is less that the max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `limit_checkBoxes()` method, you want `i < 30`, not `i > 30` in the loop.  See my embedded comment.

```
    label.setText(Integer.toString(number_of_boxes_checked));
    if (number_of_boxes_checked > 6) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) { //<- your bug was here, I fixed it
            checkBox[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
        ++number_of_boxes_checked;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I made such a easy mistake.

Comment: As a side note, I was able to quickly identify the problem by just stepping through the code in a debugger when I set a breakpoint around your magic number (6)

Answer (score 0):

Change the line: `for (int i = 0; i > 30; ++i) {` with this `for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {`